# How to use SSL certificate to two ports running in the same server instance

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, openssl

Hi i am running ubuntu instance in the AWS EC2 service with Nginx server. I have React app running on port 5000 and node server on port 8080. I have added SSL using openssl certificate for my domain for HTTPS. But after running both servers the web site is not working and showing this message

[image]

As my understanding, it is because the `/api` traffic is going through 8080 and it doesn't have a SSL certificate.

my  `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`  file is like this

```html
server {
    server_name projectmatch.me www.projectmatch.me;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }


      listen 443 ssl;
     # managed by Certbot
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/projectmatch.me/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/projectmatch.me/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
      include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

  }

  server {
    if ($host = www.projectmatch.me) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = projectmatch.me) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name projectmatch.me www.projectmatch.me;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Please let me know how to add SSL to my React and Api ports.

Comment: you are requesting http content in a https site, so you have to change the api request to https

Comment: that is what i am asking for, please let me know how to do that for 2 ports in the same time.

Comment: By convention 8080 is not an SSL port, generally 8443 would be the "corresponding" ssl port for 8080. Is that doable within your application?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a second `listen` directive for the `server` block for any additional ports you want to listen on (with or without ssl).

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 8443 ssl;
    listen 80; # no ssl
}
```